# sproutcore timer usage MaxInactiveInterval

Tags: sproutcore

Two absolute beginner questions.
I have working code in my main.js enterState.

```
enterState: function(context) {
..
//keepAlive
var now = SC.DateTime.create(); 
if (now.get('hour') < 18){
    SC.info ("main_state:enterState:go %@", now.get('hour'));
    this.timer = SC.Timer.schedule({
         target: this,
         action: '_timerFired',
         interval: 5000, 
         repeats: YES
        });
    } else {
        SC.info ("MainState:enterState:nogo %@", now.get('hour'));
        };
..
    this.mainPane.append();
    },

_timerFired: function(){
        SC.info ("_timerFired %@", Date.now());
    },


exitState: function() {
        SC.info('main_state:exitState');
        this.timer.invalidate();
        this.mainPane.remove();             
    },
```

Question 1: the enterState is used every time a user goes to the main view, is the timer schedule initialized once or every time a user switches views?

Question 2: I think I need a query. e.q. the logged in username, to prevent an automatic logout due to the expired session MaxInactiveInterval. Is there sample code to get the spring username in the _timerFired function?

I saw the answer/solution of Maurits, thanks, but it is too complicated for me.

Comment: While you think it is complicated, it is the only way which actually makes sure that things are going the way you need them to go. I came to the solution I gave you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187236/how-to-deal-with-authenticated-state-in-a-sproutcore-application)  because any other solution created too much issues. Because: what are you going to do if the auth is actually lost, for example because of a lost internet connection?

Comment: Thx again. We have users how are automatically loggedoff after the MaxInactiveInterval expired. It is there wish to be kept logged in during working hours. I thought a timer and a server request would do the trick.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with grails, but that is most likely going to do the trick. What it doesn't take into account though is that because of other reasons a timeout can still occur. In those cases you would like to be able to gracefully resume the running application, for example through showing a login in the app itself, then do an XHR api call, refreshing things data wise and continue. This is why the states solution helps, as it allows you to control this situation very tightly.

Comment: ok, thanks for the quick response. But if I use the suggested seperate concurrent states for authenticated or not, then I am already to late to keep the session alive, right?

Comment: No, because this starts right up at the moment the state chart is initialized. That is why the AUTH and APPMAIN from the other question are concurrent states, they are initialized essentially at the same time, which is the runloop in which you call ```MyApp.statechart.initialize();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This timer will be scheduled every time this state is being entered. If this is the root state of the application, that will be once. If this state is used to display the mainPane and you are leaving this state somehow, and returning, then this timer will be initialized every time you enter this state.
2. You could keep the username as property of the current state (this._username) and as _timerFired is called with this being the current state (SC.Timer will take care of that through the target) you will have access to it. You'd need to set it somehow of course. Another solution is to read it directly from the controller you use for the login procedure.

Nevertheless, this solution is prone to trouble. The main reason for this is that you are creating implicit states. I mean that being authenticated is an application state, and instead of making this explicit through the state chart, you hide it within one of the states. As I wrote in the comment: I came to the solution I posted in the other question because of trying many different solutions and hitting trouble. What I learned from those issues is that the statechart is your friend, and really trying to work with it will help you avoid loads of headaches!

Comment: Some extra info, we use grails and sproutcore together. The MaxInactiveInterval is set in grails, in sproutcore we want to prevent the auto logoff.